# Why is this question downvoted too much?

Tags: discussion, down-votes, specific-question

> This question:[Why does a bicycle come to rest after travelling a distance?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/82238/31782) has been downvoted too much. Why  is it  so.

IMO OP seems to know that there should be some force which brings the bicycle to rest and is just asking for if this is true or there is some other concept involved. Since the OP does not make it clear my speculation might be wrong.

Comment: I'm one of the downvoters. I downvoted because friction is one of the first concepts one should study along with Newton's laws.

Comment: @jinawee While I was in school I read the chapter of _Friction_ after the chapter of _Newton's Laws_. It might be that OP had not read about friction.

Comment: It is worth noting that the poster already had a history by the time (s)he posted that question. This was not his/her first or even tenth question, and others had covered topic nominally more advanced than the basics of friction.

Comment: That said, "too much" is an expression of your opinion, and those votes are expressions of other people's opinions.

Comment: Note that the policy is that you are free to use downvotes. But you shouldn't use them with bad intentions. Even execellent questions have some downvotes (the converse is also true).

Comment: Let me make one thing clear I am not paranoid about downvotes. Some of my questions were deleted by community mod because they were downvoted below **5**. To have known the reasons for downvotes I could make my question on-topic. Deleted(or removed) questions are automatically off-topic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In seeing [the way the question was first posted](https://physics.stackexchange.com/revisions/82238/1), one can't expect anything better than [@ja72's comment](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/82238/#comment171089_82238).

We usually downvote because upvotes/downvotes are basically meant for whether a post is showing some **research effort** or not.

[image]

In the question, (it appears, from its looks that) the OP didn't bother to do some research on his question. I might guess that that's probably the reason behind the other downvotes.

Answer (score 5):

Here's my take: the questioner effectively says, right in the question, that they know that an object's velocity won't change without a force acting on it. Then they ask whether the fact that an object (the bicycle) is changing its velocity implies that a force is acting on it. This reflects a failure to apply basic logic. And the entire core of the question is based on that logical failure. So it's not a good question for us; there's no interesting physics in it.

Comment: Everyone is not intelligent. It might be the policy of Phys.SE to downvote such questions. How far a good policy is this which discriminate the unintelligent? The OP clearly knows the basic logic but he wants to know if their is some other physical phenomena or theory involved or his idea that there must be a force is correct.

Comment: Reasons for downvoting aren't exactly a matter of policy, but I would argue that's exactly the kind of justification for downvoting we want. This is a site for expert-level questions, not basic logical failures. If the OP clearly knew the basic logic and wanted to know something more interesting, he or she should have clearly said so.

Comment: "This is a site for expert-level questions." Would you give me the link for further details about this policy.

Comment: Why, what sort of further details are you looking for? Most of it is in the help center.

Comment: I could not find this info in help page. Is there some kind of discussion available on meta?

Comment: What exactly are you looking for a discussion of? I'm not clear on that.

Comment: You say:"_"This is a site for expert-level questions._" Who has decided this? Where it is written?

Comment: Oh, that. Well for one thing, it's in giant text on the [home page of the Stack Exchange network](https://stackexchange.com/). I'm sure you can also find many answers saying this on [metaSE].

Comment: It says:"_expert answers to your questions_". If I am reading it correct then it means that ask a question and get an answer from the experts. It does not mean that the questions are ought to be of expert level.

Comment: I have looked on Meta.SE everyone says that the questions should show some research effort, be it expert level or beginner level.e.g. [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121330/is-stackexchange-supposed-to-be-just-for-experts). I have seen that diff sites have diff policies e.g. Math.SE allows homework and beginner question. What is the policy for Phys.SE? Is it same as of Stackoverflow? I do not find the text "This is a site for expert-level questions." anywhere.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14011/discussion-between-david-z-and-anupam)

Comment: David, [this](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/5731/why-this-question-is-downvoted-too-much#comment16918_5735) comment of mine is my personal opinion. Rest of my comments were about your expert-level statement.